# Script to recursively check permissions and owners of a directory and write shell script to recreate them

Tags: linux, permissions, backup

I'm trying to write a shell script to preserve and rewrite all permissions/groups in a large directory with several subdirectories in the event they get changed or are not properly created or if mirroring the users/permissions for this directory on a different machine.

**Something like:**

```
chown adam:brown /var/blarg
chmod 770 /var/blarg
chown adam:brown /var/blarg/toast.file
chmod 777 /var/blarg/toast.file

...etc
```

Doing this by hand will take a long time. I was wondering is there an existing command/script to accomplish this task?

Comment: Why not `chown -R adam:brown /var/blarg` and `chmod -R 770 /var/blarg`? If not, can you please clarify where these files are. A single file isn't much to find a pattern.

Comment: Have a take look at monit.  http://mmonit.com/monit/

Comment: @Patrick It's a large directory with many sub directories of varying depth

Comment: Play with something like `find . -printf 'chown %u:%g %p\n'`. `man find` will show how to print out the other properties you are interested in too...

Comment: @yeti Thanks! That seems to be what I was looking for. For the permissions I used `find . -printf 'chmod %m %p\n'` Why don't your add this as an answer to this question so I can accept it?

Comment: @blarg Just give the points to the 1st one who writes this down in a pretty way... migraine caught me and I'm only good for telegram like short answers today...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As yeti suggested in the comments, I used the find command to find all files and directories  within the directory and output their permissions/owners into a chown or chmod command. I added the verbose `-v` option so when running the resulting shell scripts you can see the success/errors of the commands:

```
find /var/blarg -printf 'chown -v %u:%g %p\n' > chowns.sh
find /var/blarg -printf 'chmod -v %m %p\n' > chmods.sh
```

Now just make the resulting .sh files executable:

```
chmod +x chowns.sh; chmod +x chmods.sh
```

Then run them and output the verbose feedback to a txt file:

```
./chmods > chmods_results.txt
```

Boom.

Comment: You just reinvented `chown -R` and `chmod -R`. Albeit worse now, as if any of your filenames have spaces or other special characters, it'll break.

Comment: How? It's much more intricate than chown/chmod -R. Those commands can only set the whole folder recursively to one user/set of permissions.

Comment: Which is exactly what your custom solution just did...

Comment: @Patrick. Try reading through it. My solution has read all current permissions for each individual directory/file using find and saved them a separate command in a shell script. E.G. a directory contains 3 files each owned by a separate user. Your solution can only assign them to one user. Mine can assign them to all three seperately. The idea is to take an existing directory on one machine and mirror the permissions on another, or repair them if changed.

Comment: ahh, you want to preserve the current permissions so you can reapply them in the future. Ok, that makes sense then. Would you mind clarifying that in your question? The only thing that even hints at it is the title.

Comment: OK amended. I thought it was clear enough as the other answers seemed to comprehend the situation.

Answer (score 3):

Along the lines of @yeti's comment, I thought about this a while back, and seem to remember coming to the conclusion that something like

```
find /path/to/dir -printf '%m\t%u\t%g\t%p\0' > filelist
```

and then

```
while read -rd $'\0' perms user group file; do 
  if [ -e "$file" ]; then
    chown "$user:$group" "$file"
    chmod "$perms" "$file"
  else
    echo "warning: $file not found"
  fi
done < filelist
```

would work. Putting the filename last in the output and using `read` and null terminators instead of newlines *should* make it safe even for filenames with spaces and other special characters. Depending where you want to run the second command from, it might be more convenient to use the filename with the leading `/path/to/dir` component from the `find` command removed i.e. `%P` in place of `%p`.

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Thanks @steeldriver

Answer (score 0):

You mention `events`, and if you have *really* many files it makes sense to watch for these. You may want to have a look at `inotifywatch`, which  "listens for filesystem events" , e.g. change of file permissions. On debian based OS it resides in package `inotify-tools` .